# When does a quadratic inequality have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Consider the following quadratic inequality:

$$x^T Q x + c^T x \leq b$$

for $x\in \Re^{d}$. When does this system have a solution?

Without loss of generality assume that $Q$ is symmetric.

Looking for a complete answer for all cases where $Q$ is 1) positive definite, 2) positive semi-definite, 3) negative definite, 4) negative semi-definite, and 5) indefinite.

It is a useful question with a nice application in quadratically-constrained optimization problems, in which the feasible space is defined by a set of constraints such as the one given above. The answer helps to quickly determine whether a system of quadratic constraints has any feasible solution or not in the preprocessing phase. In fact, if any of the quadratic constraints has no solution, the solver informs that the problem is infeasible before starting the main optimization procedure.

Comment: Is $Q$ definite positive?

Comment: @NN2 I don't have any constraints on $Q$, but if $Q$ being semidefinite helps, sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that $Q$ is definite positive and invertible matrix.

As $Q$ is definite positive, we can write  $Q = A^TA$ (the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the [square root](https://yutsumura.com/a-positive-definite-matrix-has-a-unique-positive-definite-square-root/) of the matrix $Q$).

As $Q$ is invertible, $A$ is also invertible matrix.

Then:
$$\begin{align}
&\iff (Ax)^T(Ax) + c^T x \le b\\
&\iff (Ax)^T(Ax) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot c^TA^{-1}\right) Ax + (Ax)^T \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\cdot c^TA^{-1}\right)  \le b\\
&\iff (Ax)^T(Ax) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot c^TA^{-1}\right) Ax + (Ax)^T \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2}\cdot A^{-T}c\right) + \frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TA^{-1}\cdot A^{-T}c \le b+ \frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TA^{-1}\cdot A^{-T}c\\
&\iff \left( Ax+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot A^{-T}c\right)^T \left( Ax+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot A^{-T}c\right) \le b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c 
\end{align}$$

- If  $b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c<0$, the problem has no solution.
- If $b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c  \ge 0$, let us make an affine transformation by denoting $$y = Ax+ \frac{1}{2}\cdot A^{-T}c  \in \mathbb{R}^n$$

  Then,
  $$\iff y^Ty \le b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c  \iff \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2 \le b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c$$
  We have infinite solutions $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ inside a n-hypersphere centered at the origine $O$ with radius $\sqrt{b+\frac{1}{4}\cdot c^TQ^{-1}c}$. These solutions $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be found by the inverse of the affine transformation
  $$x = A^{-1} \left(y-  \frac{1}{2}\cdot A^{-T}c\right) = A^{-1}y - \frac{1}{2}\cdot Q^{-1}c$$

Comment: Could you solve the other cases?

Comment: @Amir What other cases do you mean?

Comment: There are five cases where $Q$ is 1) positive definite, 2) positive semi-definite, 3) negative definite, 4) negative semi-definite, and 5) indefinite. Could you also discuss cases 2 to 4.

Comment: @Amir These cases are not very difficult but still long to write. And the question was already closed. So, I suggest that you write a new question and ask for each specific case.

Comment: I see, but I think they may close the new one again. I tried to reopen it, but they did not agree. Do not why it was closed. You may help to find the reason.    By the way,  the 1st and 2nd may be considred as the complement of the 3rd and 4th. But I guess the 5th case may be np-hard.